# Permissions Granted When Aspect Is Apllied

Tags: configuration, permissions, alfresco

I know this and issue that has been addressed several times in the Alfresco forums:

http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/content-modeling/permissions-controlled-based-content-aspects-10022006
http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/content-modeling/permission-aspect-05022008-1510

And there is also some documentations that tackles the matter:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Security_and_Authentication#How_to_add_your_own_type_or_aspect.2C_assign_permissions_for_it.2C_configure_it_and_secure_a_service_that_uses_it_....

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/PermissionModelDTD

In few words, I'm trying to grant existing permission group 'CreateChildren' to 'Consumer' if a specific aspect is applied. This is what I have added to my custom 'permissionDefinitios.xml' (I have omitted default XML content):

#### Import my custom namespace

```
<namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/mynamespace/1.0" prefix="my"/>
```

#### Define a permission group for 'my:aspect' aspect. I want this permission group to include the existing 'CreateChildren' permission group

```
<permissionGroup name="CreateComments" requiresType="true" expose="false">
    <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="CreateChildren" type="sys:base" />
</permissionGroup>
```

#### Grant the previously defined permission group to the 'Consumer' role for type 'my:aspect'

```
<!-- The Consumer permission allows read to everything by default.                  -->
<permissionGroup name="Consumer" allowFullControl="false" expose="true" >
    <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="Read"/>
    <includePermissionGroup type="my:aspect" permissionGroup="CreateComment"/>
</permissionGroup>
```

The result of this setup is that users with 'Consumer' role can create children in any site by default, regardless the aspect is applied on the node or not. Am I doing anything wrong? Is this the result expected for such configuration?

Since I taken the 'ownable' model or example, I'm wondering whether the problem might be the fact that I'm using the existing permission 'CreateChildren' instead of completely defining custom low level permissions and permission groups. I have also noticed that there is a service for the 'ownable' aspect, might I need to implement my service as well? I don't so, since this service looks to have to with policies implementation, which I think I don't as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing this check with a dynamic authority? Look at for example the OwnerDynamicAuthority.java in the alfresco source. With this approach you can just check if the node has the aspect and if it has give the user createChildren permission for this node.

Comment: TBH I haven't tried to implement it with a dynamic authority but sounds good. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I think I have stumbled upon a pitfall with the dynamic authority way to handle permissions. Once we upgraded a installation to Solr, the result sets are faulty. My guess is this is because Solr stores the ACL:s in the index. When implementing a dynamic authority the way we have done (granting access when a user is in the end of an association) there is no way to store this information in the solr index. I will raise this with support, but my guess is I will have to refactor the whole implementation. :(

Comment: I really appreciate that you have shared this information. I haven't tried it out the approach of a dynamic authority yet, but what I understand from your words is that the approach is not necessarily wrong, but the way you have implemented it. There are out-of-the-box dynamic authorities implemented in Alfresco, like for the "ownable" and "lockable" aspects, aren't there?

Comment: Yes that is correct. They have probably tweaked solr to handle those types of dynamic authorities in some way. I would not say we implemented it the wrong way since it works perfectly with lucene, and since Alfresco have not in any way stated that the implementation of a dynamic authority would break the search results in any way. I have opened a support ticket and are awaiting some kind of response. I'll post again when I have something to share.